# PHP - Count array based on other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
$array1 = array(Array('b','d'), 
                Array('c','a'),
                Array('b','d'),
                Array('a','d'),
                Array('c'),
                Array('c'),
                Array('a','d','e'),
                Array('d','b')
                 );

$array2 = array(array('c'),array('a','d'), array('b','d'), array('a,','d','e')) ;
$result = array();
```

Here's my code:

```
    foreach ($array2 as $part) {
        $key = implode(', ', $part);
        if( ! array_key_exists ($key, $array1)) {
            $result[$key] = 0;
        }
        $result[$key] = $result[$key] + 1;
    }
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        echo "$value of {$key}<br/>";   
    }
```

I want to count values $array2 based on $array1
I got this one:

```
1 of c      
1 of a, d
1 of b, d  
1 of a, d, e
```

But I want a result like this:

```
3 of c      
2 of a, d
2 of b, d  
1 of a, d, e
```

If anybody wonders why there's (2 of a,d), it from `array('a','d')` and `array('a','d','e')`

Comment: You are not actually asking us to write the code for you, are you?:) What have you tried so far to achieve your expected result?

Comment: have you tried outputting the value of `$key` after your `implode` - I have a feeling you're trying to implode an array that doesn't need imploding, so your `array_key_exists` isn't returning a value.

Comment: sorry i'm still newbie, that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
$result = array();
$array1 = array(
    array('b','d'), 
    array('c','a'),
    array('b','d'),
    array('a','d'),
    array('c'),
    array('c'),
    array('a','d','e'),
    array('d','b')
);
$array2 = array(
    array('c'),
    array('a','d'),
    array('b','d'),
    array('a,','d','e')
);

foreach ($array2 as $part) {
    $key = implode(', ', $part);
    if(!array_key_exists ($key, $array1)) {
        $result[$key] = 0;
    }
    foreach($array1 as $data) {
        $dataKey = implode(', ', $data);
        if(strpos($dataKey, $key) > -1) {
            $result[$key]++;
        }
    }

}
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value of {$key}<br/>";   
}
```

The result it produces is:

```
3 of c
2 of a, d
2 of b, d
0 of a,, d, e
```

Notice the `0 of a,, d, e`. This is caused by a typo in your `$array2` - `array('a,','d','e')`